# Рассылка сообщений всем пользователям бота Python(pyTelegramBotApi)

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Имеется бот, в котором реализована форма регистрации и сохранения пользователей в БД(MySQL), есть user_id в котором сохраняется id пользователя. Задача в том, чтобы сделать рассылку всем пользователям бота. Не могу разобраться как это сделать. user_id == chat_id не работает или же не так что то сам сделал. Спасибо за Ваше внимание

Answer (score 1):

Было бы неплохо увидеть код. Попробуйте для начала загрузить данные с базы в список потом пройдись циклом.
в декораторе соединения поставьте свои данные

import pymysql

```
def view_data(connection, table_name):
    """ Показать таблицу базы данных"""
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        select_all_data = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}"
        cursor.execute(select_all_data)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        print(f'Данные из таблицы {table_name}')
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
        print('#' * 30)


def connection_func(func):
    """Декоратор для соебинения с базой данных"""

    def camel(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            connection = pymysql.connect(
                host=host,
                port=port,
                user=user,
                password=password,
                database=db_name,
                cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
            )
            print('successfully connected...')
            print('#' * 30)
            try:
                result = func(connection, *args, **kwargs)
            
                return result
            finally:
                connection.close()
        except Exception as exp:
            print('Connection refused...')
            print(f'FAIL{exp}')

    return camel

def upload_users_data(connection):
    """Выгрузка данных пользователя из базы данных"""
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        select_all_data = "SELECT * FROM `users`"
        cursor.execute(select_all_data)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        print(f'•• DATA USERS\n'
              f'{"Name":<10} {"ID":<10} Progress')
        return rows




for user_id in user_id_list:
    bot.send_message(user_id, “текст рассылки”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сохранить user_id в список. После чего пройтись по всем user_id и выполнить send_message